# Удалить папку с бекслешем

Tags: php

При попытки удалить директорию, которая содержит обратный слеш - удаляются все папки, которые находятся на том же уровне, что и удаляемая:

```
rmdir('path/to/folder/folder\\name');
```

Comment: А всё-таки очень желательно получить уточнение: у вас папка, которая так и называется `folder\name` прямо со слэшем в её названии, так?

Comment: @andreymal ага..

Comment: Возможно вот это поможет - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19462883/6004176 . Не могу попробовать - на винде нельзя такую папку создать

Comment: В РНР для указания обратного слеша нужно использовать 4 знака ``\``: `rmdir('path/to/folder/folder\\\\name');`